# My App crashes when items in Listview overflows

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

App i am trying to build crashes whenever items in listview overflows.
It works fine when items are limited(<19).
Please help.
Any coding tips are also welcome as i am a newbie.

This is console output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.kmb.budget, PID: 5394
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:9446)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:4549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:928)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:15709)
        at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:10901)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:1168)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:615)
>>>>        at com.kmb.budget.TransactionsActivity.createTransactionList(TransactionsActivity.java:35)
>>>>        at com.kmb.budget.DBClass.doInBackground(DBClass.java:116)
>>>>        at com.kmb.budget.DBClass.doInBackground(DBClass.java:14)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

part of DBClass resposible to handle function.
Scroll down. I had marked main lines with ">>>".

```
class DBClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

    private MainDatabase db ;
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private TransactionsActivity tActivity;
    private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
    private TransactionDAO transactionDAO;
    private String nm;
    private String tp;
    private String operation;
    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String comment;
    private int amount;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date transactionDate;

    public DBClass(Context context,TransactionsActivity activity,String operation){
        this.db = MainDatabase.getMainDatabase(context);
        this.categoryDAO = db.categoryDAO();
        this.transactionDAO = db.transactionDAO();
        this.tActivity = activity;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public DBClass(Context context,MainActivity activity,String operation){
        this.db = MainDatabase.getMainDatabase(context);
        this.categoryDAO = db.categoryDAO();
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public DBClass(Context context, String nm, String tp){
        this.db = MainDatabase.getMainDatabase(context);
        this.categoryDAO = db.categoryDAO();
        this.nm = nm;
        this.tp = tp;
        this.operation = "CATEGORY";
    }
    public DBClass(Context context, String to, String from, String comment, int amount, Date createDate, Date transactionDate) {
        this.db = MainDatabase.getMainDatabase(context);
        this.transactionDAO = db.transactionDAO();
        this.categoryDAO = db.categoryDAO();
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.operation = "TRANSACTION";
        this.comment = comment;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        int st = 0;
        switch(operation){
            case("CATEGORY"):
                CategoryModal category = new CategoryModal();
                category.setCategoryName(nm);
                category.setType(tp);
                categoryDAO.insertCategory(category);
                Log.i("Category created",nm);
                long a = categoryDAO.getCategoryId(nm);
                Log.i("Ccategory id in db",Long.toString(a));
                List<String> categ= categoryDAO.getAllCategoryNames();
                for(String cm : categ){
                    Log.i("category name" , cm);
                }
                break;
            case("TRANSACTION"):
                TransactionModal transaction = new TransactionModal();
                transaction.setToId(categoryDAO.getCategoryId(to));
                transaction.setFromId(categoryDAO.getCategoryId(from));
                transaction.setComment(comment);
                transaction.setAmount(amount);
                transaction.setTransactionDate(transactionDate);
                transaction.setCreateDate(createDate);
                transactionDAO.insert(transaction);
                Log.e("transaction",transaction.getComment());
                break;
            case("GET_CATEGORIES"):
                try {
                    mActivity.setList(categoryDAO.getAllCategoryNames());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mActivity.setList(null);
                }

                Log.i("category call","done");
                break;
            case("GET_TRANSACTIONS"):
>>>                List<TransactionModal> tmlist = transactionDAO.getAllTransactions();
>>>                List<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<>();
>>>                int i = 1;
>>>                List<CategoryModal> cm = categoryDAO.getAllCategories();
>>>                for(TransactionModal tm : tmlist){
>>>                    Long fromId = tm.getFromId();
>>>                    Long toId = tm.getToId();
>>>                    Transaction t = new Transaction(Integer.toString(i),categoryDAO.getCategoryName(fromId),categoryDAO.getCategoryName(toId),tm.getComment(),tm.getTransactionDate().toString(),Integer.toString(tm.getAmount()));
>>>                    CategoryModal cmc = categoryDAO.getCategoryById(tm.getFromId());
>>>                    String to = cmc.getCategoryName();
>>>                    list.add(t);
>>>                    i++;
>>>                }
>>>                tActivity.createTransactionList(list);

                break;
            case("convertOperation"):
                break;
        }
        return st;
    }



}
```

this is transaction activity

```
27    public void createTransactionList(List<Transaction> list){
28        Transaction header = new Transaction("SR","From","To","Comment","Date","Amount");
29        List<Transaction> temp = new ArrayList<>();
30        temp.add(header);
31        temp.addAll(list);
32        ListView transactionListView = findViewById(R.id.transactions_listView);
33        List<Transaction> transactionsList = temp;
34        TransactionListAdapter tLAdapter = new TransactionListAdapter(this,R.layout.transaction_list_adapter,transactionsList);
35        transactionListView.setAdapter(tLAdapter);
36    }
```

this is conent_transaction.xml which contains listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".TransactionsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_transactions">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/transactions_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit 1:
Transaction list adapter

```
class TransactionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction> {


    private Context context;
    private int resource;


    /**
     * Default constructor for transaction adapter
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param objects
     */
    public TransactionListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Transaction> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        String sr = getItem(position).getSr();
        String from = getItem(position).getFrom();
        String to = getItem(position).getTo();
        String comment = getItem(position).getComment();
        String date = getItem(position).getDate();
        String amount = getItem(position).getAmount();

        Transaction transaction = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource,parent,false);
        TextView tvSr = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_sr);
        TextView tvTo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_to);
        TextView tvFrom = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_from);
        TextView tvComment = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_comment);
        TextView tvDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_td);
        TextView tvAmount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tr_list_amount);
        tvSr.setText(sr);
        tvTo.setText(to);
        tvFrom.setText(from);
        tvComment.setText(comment);
        tvAmount.setText(amount);
        tvDate.setText(date);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

overflows: increase beyond a certain number which can be viewed on screen

Comment: Post the code for adapter!

Comment: You try to update `View` from inside AsyncTask's `doInBackground()`, which is not permissible. Add more details of your `DBClass `

Comment: I had added full DBClass. Scroll the code where i had marked the specific code. I fetch transaction list from db and then call a method in activity with list as parameter to pass the list. It works fine if there are limited items in list. it throws error when list of items overflows the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to update `View` from inside AsyncTask's `doInBackground()`, which is not permissible. Update your `DBClass` like below:

```
class DBClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<?>> {

    ....

    @Override
    protected List<?> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        List mList = null;

        switch(operation) {

            ....

            case("GET_CATEGORIES"):
                try {
                    mList = categoryDAO.getAllCategoryNames();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case("GET_TRANSACTIONS"):
                ....

                mList = list;
                break;
        }

        return mList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<?> list) {
        switch(operation) {
            case("GET_CATEGORIES"):
                mActivity.setList(list);
                break;
            case("GET_TRANSACTIONS"):
                tActivity.createTransactionList(list);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very Much sir. It works. Any tips regarding my coding practice as i am new to android?

Comment: You are welcome @K.M.B. First try to clear basic concept of `Android`, then dive into deep.

Answer (score 1):

According to your exception log

`Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

Crash happened because you try to update view in non UI thread. Pls provide code where you use AsyncTask

Comment: i had added full code of DBClass which extends AsyncTask